# remove conda environment and package directories so that it doesn't show under conda config --show-sources

Tags: python, conda

Perhaps this is my lack of understanding of how conda environments/ packages works, and if it is an issue of general conda use, or specific to the university computer cluster I use, but when I run:

```
conda config --show-sources
```

I get:

```
==> /home/user_number/.condarc <==
envs_dirs:
  - /path/to/a/anaconda/envs
  - /path/to/a/anaconda/envs2
  - /different_path/to/a/anaconda/envs
pkgs_dirs:
  - /path/to/a/anaconda/pkgs
  - /path/to/a/anaconda/pkgs2
  - /different_path/to/a/anaconda/pkgs
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - bioconda
  - defaults}
```

I would like to remove it so that I only have just one environment and package directory, something like this:

```
==> /home/user_number/.condarc <==
envs_dirs:
  - /path/to/a/anaconda/envs
pkgs_dirs:
  - /path/to/a/anaconda/pkgs
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - bioconda
  - defaults
```

I have tried the below, and neither remove it from the list

```
conda env remove -p /path/to/a/anaconda/envs2
conda-env remove -p /path/to/a/anaconda/envs2
```

It returns:

```
Remove all packages in environment /path/to/a/anaconda/envs2
Proceed ([y]/n)? y
```

but I want it to remove the environment directory itself - is it just emptying the directory rather than removing it?

Answer (score 0):

Either edit the `.condarc` file directly, or use the `conda config` command to remove the unwanted ones:

```bash
conda config --remove envs_dirs /path/to/a/anaconda/envs2
conda config --remove envs_dirs /different_path/to/a/anaconda/envs

conda config --remove pkgs_dirs /path/to/a/anaconda/pkgs2
conda config --remove pkgs_dirs /different_path/to/a/anaconda/pkgs
```

Note this will not remove the directories, only stop Conda from looking there. You may want to manually remove the directories after this.

Also, some environments may still appear listed in `conda env list` due to being added to `~/.conda/environments.txt`. One can manually remove any environments from here if they are unwanted.

In general, this looks like someone installed Anaconda multiple times, which is not recommended.